# Don't update SQLite database with parameters method

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

As I've written, I don't manage to update my SQLite Database using parameters method.

Here is the code:

```
using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BarMalnate.sqlite;Version=3;"))
{
    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE Concorso SET Controlla = @Controlla WHERE Numero = @Numero", cnn))
    {
        //example variable 
        int num = 2;
        int mynum = 2;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(new SQLiteParameter[] 
        {
            new SQLiteParameter("@Controlla", DbType.Int32){ Value = num},
            new SQLiteParameter("@Numero", DbType.Int32){ Value = mynum}
        });
        cnn.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the question? Do you want to say that the code you've posted is not working?

Comment: Yes, i've no errors, but the database not update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because database file gets overwritten every time you run the project. Make sure your database file (*.db3/*.db) is included in the project and its **Copy to Output** property is set to **Never Copy** or **Copy if Newer**.

Comment: If i try to set Copy To Output property to Never Copy it gives me an error "SQLite error
no such table: Concorso"
If i try to set Copy To Output property to Copy id newer, nothing happened, i have not errors but the db does not update

Comment: Your code appears ok. Place a breakpoint in it and check if it is actually executing. Also use a try/catch block around the code and verify there's no exception.